# Generate Summary report from logs : Peform additions on output of a command ( using AWK / SED or any other way) and formatting output

Tags: shell, sed, awk, summary, calculated-field

I am processing several files at a time.Each of which has summary stats . At the end of the process I want to create a summary file that will add up all the stats .
I already know how to dig out the stats from the log files. But I want to be able to add the numbers and echo to another file 
Here is what I use to dig out the times .

```
find . -iname "$srch1*" -exec grep "It took" {} \; -print
```

output would be like this

```
    It took 0 hours, 11 minutes and 4 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000010-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log
It took 0 hours, 11 minutes and 56 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000007-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log
It took 0 hours, 29 minutes and 54 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000001-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log
It took 0 hours, 22 minutes and 33 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000004-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log
It took 0 hours, 59 minutes and 38 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000000-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log
It took 0 hours, 11 minutes and 50 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000005-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log
It took 0 hours, 22 minutes and 10 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000002-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log
It took 0 hours, 10 minutes and 39 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000008-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log
It took 0 hours, 12 minutes and 27 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000009-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log
It took 0 hours, 22 minutes and 36 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000003-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log
It took 0 hours, 11 minutes and 40 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000006-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log
```

what I want is something like this

```
Summary 
filepart000006-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log  0 hours, 11 minutes and 40 seconds
```

then find out the LONGEST times among them and output some message like .

```
 Total time taken =____________
```

I am running in parallel so the time taken is the longest one.

then do some calculations like this.

```
find . -iname "$srch*" -exec grep "Processed Files" {} \; -print

        Processed Files:   7936635
./filename-20131102-part000000-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log
        Processed Files:   3264805
./filename-20131102-part000001-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log
        Processed Files:   1607547
./filename-20131102-part000008-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log
        Processed Files:   3180478
./filename-20131102-part000003-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log
        Processed Files:   1595497
./filename-20131102-part000007-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log
        Processed Files:   1568532
./filename-20131102-part000009-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log
        Processed Files:   3259884
./filename-20131102-part000002-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log
        Processed Files:   3141542
./filename-20131102-part000004-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log
        Processed Files:   3124221
./filename-20131102-part000005-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log
        Processed Files:   3136845
./filename-20131102-part000006-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log
```

and if I want just the metrics

```
( find . -iname "dl-aster-full-20131102*" -exec grep "Processed Files" {} \;) | cut -d":" -f2
   7936635
   3264805
   1607547
   3180478
   1595497
   1568532
   3259884
   3141542
   3124221
   3136845
```

Based on the above 2 just create a summary file .

```
Filename                                                  Processed files 
filename-20131102-part000000-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log   7936635
```

....
then a summary which is all the above added.

```
   ( 7936635 +
   3264805 +
   1607547 +
   3180478.....etc
   1595497
   1568532
   3259884
   3141542
   3124221
   3136845 ) as 


 Total Files = ____________
```

so overall like this one .

```
Filename                                                  Processed files 
    filename-20131102-part000000-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log   7936635
     Total Files = ____________ ( sum of all above )
```

All that that needs to be done is 
-- Get the output in format

```
 Filename                                                  Processed files 
    filename-20131102-part000000-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log   7936635
```

in my above command they are on different line 
and then perform summation for the numbers already outputted.

My Question is .
--  How can I perform addition like above -  using anything. I'd avoid PERL , since I am not sure , it'd be installed everywhere where the shell is run 
-- How can I format the output like above .
I already know how to extract the output

Comment: So what is your _question_ ?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have to use sed and awk?  If I were given a problem like this, I would most likely use Perl.

Comment: @MichaelMilom well, you know, `gawk` (GNU awk) is enough for the task but it's unclear what's the problem exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with below sed command, you can get the output (filename and grep result into one line), then the next will be easy for you.
**(the grep result should be only one line for each file)**

```
find . -iname "$srch1*" -exec grep "It took" {} \; -print |sed -r 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/'

./filepart000010-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log    It took 0 hours, 11 minutes and 4 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000007-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log It took 0 hours, 11 minutes and 56 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000001-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log It took 0 hours, 29 minutes and 54 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000004-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log It took 0 hours, 22 minutes and 33 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000000-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log It took 0 hours, 59 minutes and 38 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000005-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log It took 0 hours, 11 minutes and 50 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000002-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log It took 0 hours, 22 minutes and 10 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000008-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log It took 0 hours, 10 minutes and 39 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000009-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log It took 0 hours, 12 minutes and 27 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000003-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log It took 0 hours, 22 minutes and 36 seconds to process that file.
./filepart000006-20140204-154923.dat.gz.log It took 0 hours, 11 minutes and 40 seconds to process that file.


find . -iname "$srch*" -exec grep "Processed Files" {} \; -print| sed -r 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' 
./filename-20131102-part000000-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log         Processed Files:   7936635
./filename-20131102-part000001-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log         Processed Files:   3264805
./filename-20131102-part000008-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log         Processed Files:   1607547
./filename-20131102-part000003-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log         Processed Files:   3180478
./filename-20131102-part000007-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log         Processed Files:   1595497
./filename-20131102-part000009-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log         Processed Files:   1568532
./filename-20131102-part000002-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log         Processed Files:   3259884
./filename-20131102-part000004-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log         Processed Files:   3141542
./filename-20131102-part000005-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log         Processed Files:   3124221
./filename-20131102-part000006-20140204-153310.dat.gz.log         Processed Files:   3136845
```

If you need calculate the longest time and total time, use below script (you should be fine to format the output.)

```
find . -iname "$srch1*" -exec grep "It took" {} \; -print |sed -r 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' > temp1
awk 'function s2t(x) { h=int(x/3600);m=int((x-h*3600)/60);s=x-h*3600-m*60}
{a=$4*3600+$6*60+$9;max=a>max?a:max;t+=a}
END{ s2t(max);print "max is",h,m,s;
s2t(t);print "sum is " ,h,m,s}' temp1

max is 0 59 38
sum is  3 46 27
```

for second one:

```
find . -iname "$srch*" -exec grep "Processed Files" {} \; -print| sed -r 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/'  > temp2
awk '{sum+=$NF}END{print "Total Files = ", sum}' temp2

Total Files =  31815986
```

Comment: Thx .How do I do a comparison of the times. e.g. 0 hours, 11 minutes and 40 seconds and find the longest time.TO get the total files- I'll just push those numbers into an array and add the contents ? or a better approach

Comment: updated, try do something by yourself first, with that you can learn quicker.

Comment: Thanks galore  I will.